# WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader was unable to detect defaults

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

I have a multi-module maven project with the structure provided.

[image]

My configuration files are provided,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
public class EllaFilterConfigHolder {

    private boolean internalBuyerFilterEnabled;
    private boolean externalBuyerFilterEnabled;

    private final Set<Integer> shopIdsToFilterSet = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The `EllaConfiguration` code,

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan( "com.ratepay.iris.ella" )
public class EllaConfiguration {

    public static final String ELLA_CONNECTOR_BEAN_NAME = "ellaConnector";
    public static final String ELLA_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR_NAME = "ellaThreadPoolTaskExecutor";

    public static final String URI_CONFIG_KEY = "ella.uri";
    public static final String CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG_KEY = "ella.connection_timeout";
    public static final String READ_TIMEOUT_CONFIG_KEY = "ella.read_timeout";

   public static final int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 100;
   public static final int DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT = 800;

    @Bean( ELLA_CONNECTOR_BEAN_NAME )
    public EntityServiceConnectable<EllaResponseDto> ellaConnector( final Environment env ) {
    return ServiceConnectorBuilder.create( createConnectionConfiguration( env ) ).timeout( createTimeoutConfiguration( env ) ).build();
}

// ========================================================================

private PostConnectionConfiguration<EllaResponseDto> createConnectionConfiguration( final Environment env ) {
    return new SimplePostConnectionConfiguration<>( env.getRequiredProperty( URI_CONFIG_KEY ), EllaResponseDto.class );
}

// ========================================================================

private SimpleTimeoutConfiguration createTimeoutConfiguration( final Environment env ) {
    return new SimpleTimeoutConfiguration( env.getProperty( CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG_KEY, Integer.class, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT ),
                                           env.getProperty( READ_TIMEOUT_CONFIG_KEY, Integer.class, DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT ) );
}

// ========================================================================

@Bean( ELLA_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR_NAME )
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.initialize();

    return taskExecutor;
   }
}
```

Finally, the `EllaServiceConfiguration` code,

```
@Configuration
@Import( EllaConfiguration.class )
public class EllaServiceConfiguration {

    private static final String SHOP_ID_STRING_SEPARATOR = ",";

    public static final String ELLA_SHOP_ID_FILTER_ENABLED_KEY = "ella.shop.id.filter";
    public static final String ELLA_INTERNAL_BUYER_FILTER_ENABLED_KEY = "ella.internal.buyer.filter";
    public static final String ELLA_EXTERNAL_BUYER_FILTER_ENABLED_KEY = "ella.external.buyer.filter";

    @Bean
    public EllaFilterConfigHolder ellaFilterConfigHolder( final Environment environment ) {

        final EllaFilterConfigHolder configHolder = new EllaFilterConfigHolder();

        configHolder
                .setInternalBuyerFilterEnabled( environment.getRequiredProperty( ELLA_INTERNAL_BUYER_FILTER_ENABLED_KEY, Boolean.class ) );
        configHolder
                .setExternalBuyerFilterEnabled( environment.getRequiredProperty( ELLA_EXTERNAL_BUYER_FILTER_ENABLED_KEY, Boolean.class ) );

        Set<Integer> set = getShopIdsToFilterAsList( environment );
        configHolder.getShopIdsToFilterSet().addAll( set );

        return configHolder;
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private Set<Integer> getShopIdsToFilterAsList( final Environment env ) {

        String shopIdListStr = env.getRequiredProperty( ELLA_SHOP_ID_FILTER_ENABLED_KEY, String.class );

        return new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList( shopIdListStr.split( SHOP_ID_STRING_SEPARATOR ) ).stream().map( Integer::parseInt )
                                      .collect( Collectors.toSet() ) );
    }

}
```

I have a class `EllaService` and I would like to write the integration test for the class.

```
@Service
public class EllaService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( EllaService.class );

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( ELLA_CONNECTOR_BEAN_NAME )
    private EntityServiceConnectable<EllaResponseDto> connector;

    @Autowired
    private EllaFilterConfigHolder configHolder;

    @Autowired
    private EllaServiceConfiguration config;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Initialize the service.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        this.configHolder = config.ellaFilterConfigHolder( env );
    }

    // ========================================================================

    /**
     * Asynchronously call Ella. Determine if traffic is applicable for Ella and if yes forward to Ella.
     *
     * @param irisBo IrisBo object
     */
    @Async( ELLA_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR_NAME )
    public void invokeEllaAsync( final IrisBo irisBo ) {

        if( isTrafficAllowed( irisBo ) ) {
            callEllaService( irisBo );
        }
    }

    // ========================================================================

    /**
     * Call ella service without processing service response.
     *
     * @param irisBo IrisBo object
     */
    public void callEllaService( final IrisBo irisBo ) {

        HttpHeaders ellaHeaders = createRequestHeaders( irisBo );

        ServiceResponse<EllaResponseDto> response = connector.call( EllaDtoConverter.convertToRequest( irisBo ), ellaHeaders );

        if( !response.isSuccess() ) {
            LOG.error( "ERROR occured while calling ella async [ irisBo: {} - response: {}]", response, irisBo );
        }
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private boolean isTrafficAllowed( IrisBo irisBo ) {

        if( configHolder.isExternalBuyerFilterEnabled() && irisBo.getBuyer().isExternalKnownCustomer() ) {
            return false;
        }

        if( configHolder.isInternalBuyerFilterEnabled() && irisBo.getBuyer().isInternalKnownCustomer() ) {
            return false;
        }

        return isShopNotConfigured( irisBo );
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private boolean isShopNotConfigured( IrisBo irisBo ) {
        return !configHolder.getShopIdsToFilterSet().contains( irisBo.getOrder().getShopId() );
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private HttpHeaders createRequestHeaders( final IrisBo irisBo ) {

        HttpHeaders ellaHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        ellaHeaders.add( ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE );
        ellaHeaders.add( CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE );

        RatepayHeaders.append( ellaHeaders, irisBo.getRequestInfo() );

        return ellaHeaders;
    }

}
```

I make the boiler-plate code for the integration test named `EllaServiceIT`,

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class EllaServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( this.wac ).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBusiness() {

        System.out.println( "XYZ" );
    }
}
```

I get the following error stack,

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.294 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.xyz.iris.ella.service.EllaServiceIT
[ERROR] initializationError(com.xyz.iris.ella.service.EllaServiceIT)  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader was unable to detect defaults, and no ApplicationContextInitializers or ContextCustomizers were declared for context configuration attributes [[ContextConfigurationAttributes@400cff1a declaringClass = 'com.xyz.iris.ella.service.EllaServiceIT', classes = '{}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoader']]
```

**Update**

I have modified the class as follows,

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { EllaServiceConfiguration.class })
@WebAppConfiguration(value = "com.ratepay.iris.ella.config")
public class EllaServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( this.wac ).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMl() {

        System.out.println( "XYZ" );
    }
}
```

I get a modified error stack provided,

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.829 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.ratepay.iris.ella.service.EllaServiceIT
[ERROR] testMl(com.ratepay.iris.ella.service.EllaServiceIT)  Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ellaService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'connector'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ellaConnector' defined in com.ratepay.iris.ella.config.EllaConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ratepay.commons.web.util.io.http.connector.EntityServiceConnectable]: Factory method 'ellaConnector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required key 'ella.uri' not found
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ellaConnector' defined in com.ratepay.iris.ella.config.EllaConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ratepay.commons.web.util.io.http.connector.EntityServiceConnectable]: Factory method 'ellaConnector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required key 'ella.uri' not found
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ratepay.commons.web.util.io.http.connector.EntityServiceConnectable]: Factory method 'ellaConnector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required key 'ella.uri' not found
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required key 'ella.uri' not found
```

How do I run it without error?